# AWS Quicksight login fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I just signed up to Quicksight and asked to enter my email address. When I enter it, the loading icon comes up for a split second and then I go right back to the page below asking me to asked to enter my email address. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Or is there a way I can unsubscribe from Quicksight in AWS and subscribe again?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue on Amazon's end. I had to contact them. It is now fixed.